# svn: is 'trunk' simply a directory?

Tags: svn, trunk

Many subversion repositories have a `trunk` subdirectory under the root of the repository.

Is the `trunk` directory in svn simply a directory with a name that follows a convention, or does the name `trunk` have special meaning hard-coded into subversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, having a `trunk` directory is simply a convention and is treated just like any other directory.  You can have a Subversion repository without a `trunk`, and you can do your daily development work out of a directory with a different name.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a convention.

However many tools that import/export export data between svn and other source control systems or tools that use the code (for example GUI interfaces) assume this convention
to handle meanings properly.

Answer (score 2):

Like Artyom and Nick Meyer have already written, it's a convention. Look at the SVN Book for more detailed information; http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html